# Python Pygame, image has white background even if it's PNG and I did not designate white background

Tags: python, image, pygame, png, transparency

I am building a silly game in Python using Pygame. I have a cat that poops. And in a previous version these poops had a transparent background. So I want to make my poops in a class for clarity of mind and control. And now my poops have a white background... I am at a loss to why this is happening.

- The images are PNG
- The images are of type surface and use 32 depth which allows for transparency.

Here is a link to my 
https://github.com/ironsketch/catPoop/blob/cat3.0/catNewGame.py

Comment: Please don't post links to your projects and include the relevant code (an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images with transparency have to be converted with [`convert_alpha`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha) instead of the `convert` method.

You could also use `convert` and then [`set_colorkey`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey), but as far as my experience goes, surfaces that are converted with `convert_alpha` are blitted a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks! I got it, and you helped! I just needed to get rid of .convert or use .convert_alpha